# Sublime Text 2 Change color of form tags: <input>, <textarea>, etc

Tags: html, colors, sublimetext2

Been trying but I'm having difficulty changing the color of specific HTML tags. I'm creating my own custom color scheme and I want all html form tags (input, textarea, select, etc.) to have a different color but I can't seem to get it right.

My code in my theme JSON file:

```
// Matching all HTML tags for now just to see if it works...doesn't work
{
    "name": "HTML form tags",
    "patterns": "</?[a-z]+(([ ]+[a-z]+([ ]*=[ ]*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">[ ]+))?)+[ ]*|[ ]*)/?>",
    "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "",
        "foreground": "#F00" // Test color (it's red for high visibility)
    }
}
```

I got the regex from [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx) and tested it in [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: Nowhere do you appear to be trying to match specific tags, you're just matching all of them. What have you tried in order to target specific tags?

Comment: Yes, I'm matching everything for now since I'm trying to see if it works. Color `#F00` is red but I don't see any red anywhere at all.